# Verbb Comments plugin - Can't see comment replies

Tags: javascript

I recently installed [Verbbs Comments plugin](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/comments/features) on my Craft site, which seems all well and good except that I can't toggle the comment replies. ('2 comments' when clicked does nothing)

[image]

Everything else works fine but that. I'm currently using the sample [CSS](https://github.com/verbb/comments/blob/craft-2/examples/comments-style.css) and [JS](https://github.com/verbb/comments/blob/craft-2/examples/standard/standard.html#L17) which was provided on their website.

I have also tried the AJAX version provided on this page:

https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/comments/docs/feature-tour/example-css-js

Not trying to override anything on this plugin, just want to get the sample up and running.

Also, no error in console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that making a slight modification to the comments.html made this work perfectly, the answer I found can be located here:

https://github.com/verbb/comments/blob/b05fd384bfbc9caed5f69df4dc72da991fef9c47/comments/templates/_forms/templates/comment.html

Answer (score 2):

I remember having to modify the javascript and templates quite extensively to get it working. Take a look at the code and find out what needs fixing. If you're using Bootstrap you can modify the template so that it uses Bootstraps buttons and dropdowns, and that's how I got it working nicely.